# When should I be using a static class variable in python?

Tags: python

When should we be using a static class variable in python? Is it only for when we are repeating ourselves in the code?

For example, the first block of code I only need to declare variable `a` once, while in the second I need to declare it multiple times in multiple methods?

```
class Test:
  a = 0
  def test(self):
    print(self.a)

  def test2(self):
    self.a+=1
    print(self.a)

  def test3(self):
    self.a += 2
    print(self.a)
```

```
class Test:
  def test(self):
    a = 0
    print(a)

  def test2(self):
    a = 0
    a += 1
    print(a)

  def test3(self):
    a = 0
    a += 2
    print(a)
```

Comment: Class variables are not visible in class methods. You can only access it through self argument. Command 'a=0' creates a local variable which lifetime ends when a function returns

Comment: You create a static variable when you will use it in multiple functions , that means without allocating more memory just to define variables that have the same value

Comment: @tstanisl Class variables are visible in methods.  Use `Test.a` for  the class variable, and `self.a` for the instance variable.

Comment: @JohnGordon, this is agrees what I have said, you can access "static" variables only indirectly via self/cls/class object/class type object/etc. I've mentioned only ```self``` because it is the most common case.

Answer (score 2):

Class variables are being shared by all instances even though your update of the form `self.a += 1` will actually assign an instance variable (but this is probably not what you want). For example:

```
>>> class Test:
...     a = 0
...     def test(self):
...         self.a += 1
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> Test.a
0
>>> t.a
0
>>> t.test()
>>> t.a
1
>>> Test.a
0
```

When you write `self.a` then Python tried to look up the name `a` on the instance and if it's not present then the class and its subclasses are considered. So the first `t.a` actually resolves as the class' `a`. However when you do `self.a += 1` this is actually a shorthand for `self.a = self.a + 1`. Here the r.h.s. `self.a` is again resolved as the class' `a`, but `self.a = ...` will set an instance attribute `a`. So from now on this instance attribute takes precedence and when you look up `t.a` or `self.a` from now on it will be the instance's value. This also means the class variable remains unchanged (as you can see from `Test.a`).

However the correct way of assigning an instance variable is in `__init__`, i.e. you'd do the following:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = a  # set the attribute on the instance 'self'
```

Class variables, as mentioned are accessible by all instances and are shared by them. This is useful for data that all instances need to access and which is common to them.

Your second example only creates local variables `a` that disappear once the function returns. They won't be accessible on the instance:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def test(self):
...         a = 0
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.test()
>>> t.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'a'
```